# Exempt file from VScode MS Python extension formatting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

I've got the Microsoft Python extension installed in VScode with the setting `"editor.formatOnSave": true` which works as expected. I would like to exempt some file from autoformatting on save. Is there a way to do this?

Visual Studio Code: 1.28.0-insider (user setup)

MS Python extension: 2018.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn settings off per-language in VS Code:

```
[python]: {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

But you cannot do it at a per-file level.